# Iterate over list of dict and return max value

Tags: python, dictionary, arraylist, nested

```
a = [{lang: 'english', count: 15}, {lang: 'spanish', count: 25}]
b = ['spanish', 'english']
```

I would like to check if the items in b list appears in a - list of dicts. (specifically in lang key).

if we have a match as we have in my example (both of b list items appears in a list of dicts),
I would like to return a new list of dict with only the item that have the max count.

For this example:

```
[{lang: 'spanish', count: 25}]
```

Can you please help me with this?
Thanks!

Comment: What have you tried so far based on your own research, and what went wrong with your attempts? A [mcve] should include your code and a description of the specific problem with that code

Comment: Shouldn't `lang` and `count` be in quotes?

Answer (score 0):

Use `max()` with a `key` argument to extract the `'count'` value and a filter to limit it to the languages in `b`:

```
>>> b = ['spanish', 'english']
>>> a = [{'lang': 'english', 'count': 15}, {'lang': 'spanish', 'count': 25}]
>>> [max((d for d in a if d['lang'] in b), key=lambda d: d['count'])]
[{'lang': 'spanish', 'count': 25}]
```